# Как реализовать движение фигуры по синусоиде c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Как реализовать движение фигуры по синусоиде на c#[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код:

```
    // объявляем переменные
    int n = 5;               // число вершин
    double R = 25, r = 50;   // радиусы
    double alpha = 1;        // поворот

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPaint();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OnPaint()
    {
        //координаты центра
        double xc = Convert.ToInt32(r * 2 / 2.0);
        double yc = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height - r * 2 / 2.0);
        Graphics e = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        e.Clear(SystemColors.Control); // стирание
        PointF[] points = new PointF[2 * n + 1];
        double a = alpha, da = Math.PI / n, l;
        for (int k = 0; k < 2 * n + 1; k++)
        {
            l = k % 2 == 0 ? r : R;
            points[k] = new PointF((float)(xc + l * Math.Cos(a)), (float)(yc + l * Math.Sin(a)));
            a += da;
        }
        e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, Convert.ToSingle(xc - r), Convert.ToSingle(yc - r), Convert.ToSingle(r * 2), Convert.ToSingle(r * 2));
        e.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points);
        e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, Convert.ToSingle(xc - R), Convert.ToSingle(yc - R), Convert.ToSingle(R * 2), Convert.ToSingle(R * 2));
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      

    }

    // При нажатии кнопки "Остановить фигуру"
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // При нажатии кнопки "Движение фигуры"
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Двигайте фигуру по горизонтали, а значение вертикали считайте по формуле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обработчике таймера наращивайте значение счётчика (глобальной переменной) и вызывайте перерисовку (например, с помощью `Invalidate`) (что приведёт с срабатыванию OnPaint)

```
 Cnt++;
```

Если при достижении края формы нужно начать сначала, обнуляйте счётчик.

При нажатии кнопки "Движение фигуры" обнуляйте счётчик, если нужно, чтобы движение начиналось из одной позиции

А в процедуре рисования OnPaint к координатам добавляйте смещение, зависящее от счетчика. Множитель при аргументе синуса определяет частоту синусоиды (и сколько её периодов уложится на экране). Например, чтобы на ширине `Wdt` уложилось два периода синусоиды, величина `freq` должна быть равна `4 * Pi / Wdt`.

```
    double freq = 0.04;       
    double xc = Convert.ToInt32(Cnt + r * 2 / 2.0);
    double yc = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height - r * 2 / 2.0 - r * Sin(freq * Cnt)));
```

Comment: Ответ то конечно классный =) но лично мое мнение: 0.04 - магическое число ничем объективно не установленное =) лучше, даже в примере, запихнуть туда переменную и отдельно описать ее, с пояснением что это и зачем. а если таки я правильно понимаю ее суть - записать всю формулу расчета, чтоб человек мог понять что это за магическое число (радианы в градусы?)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Видимо, я не сохранил правку с переменной. Добавил пример расчёта.

Comment: этот код:  double freq = 0.04;       
    double xc = Convert.ToInt32(Cnt + r * 2 / 2.0);
    double yc = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height - r * 2 / 2.0 - r * Sin(freq * Cnt))); в обработчик таймера?

Comment: Нет, в процедуре рисования. А в таймере счётчик менять и вызывать перерисовку

Comment: в OnPaint() ?  не совсем понимаю куда его впихнуть

Comment: Я же написал код - модификация строк с xc, yc в начале OnPaint